# Pre-setting today date to input type date in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I was having some problem when trying to preset today's date to HTML component using Angular Typescript. Here is my HTML component:

```
<div class="d-flex">
    <input id="field_tStartdate" type="date" class="form-control" name="tStartdate" [(ngModel)]="tStartdate" required />
</div>
```

Then in my typescript file:

```
tStartdate: string;
this.tStartdate = moment().toString();
```

However, my input field at the front end is still showing dd/MM/yyyy by default without pre-selecting today's date. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The input type date expects a value of type "YYYY-mm-DD", but `moment().toString()` ouputs "Fri Apr 05 2019 17:25:24 GMT+0200"

Try `moment().format('YYYY-mm-DD')`

Comment: Nope, it does not work. The input is still showing 'dd/mm/yyyy' instead of today's date

Comment: @hyperfkcb did you see the working example? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ayudts

Answer (score 0):

Input type date expects a date string with the format:

```
'YYYY-MM-DD'
```

For example in [moment js](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/01-format/) this looks like that:

```
moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Please be aware that upper and lower case matters, since 'mm' is Minutes while 'MM' refers to months.